# How can you beat Frank the Zombie with an assassin in Desktop Dungeons?

Tags: desktop-dungeons-2010

I have been trying and trying and it seems that what makes this a hard thing to do is because there are two bosses. I have tried this with human assassin (to maximize damage) and have been using some mid-battle leveling. I beat the other boss (a lvl 10 wraith) at level 8 (or was it 7?) and the problem was running out of other high level enemies (i was left with like 5 level 1s and a level 9+ frank.

Since everyone was immune to poison, i just converted my starting glyph to damage and my final damage (at level 9) was 85. Frank had 650+ hp and I already ran out of MPs and pots and I only had like 3 HP potions left (which wasn't enough).

Is there something I'm missing with mid-level battling? Is it really just too hard to beat with an assassin and will require some epic luck?

I have also tried polymorphing all the enemies (jehora) at one point and the wraith was transformed into a golem but frank stayed the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might qualify as epic luck, but I believe how I did it was to use an Elf

- Convert starting glyph to mana
- Find BURNDARAYZ glyph, trying to fight as few monsters as possible
- Begin worshipping Mystera Annur
- Use magic repeatedly to kill monsters and build faith, getting bonus mana reward
- Use assassin ability to kill off lower-level monsters to trigger mid-battle levelups as needed
- Eventually got bonus fireball damage
- Use large number of mana potions and mid-battle levelups to defeat bosses

I believe I also had BLUDTOPOWA to make it easier to regnerate magic points.  Anyway, while using Mystera probably isn't a must, the key is that you will need to make good use of your magic as well as your ability to instantly kill lower level monsters.  HALPMEH can be very effective for classes that do a large amount of physical damage.

Comment: i actually tried that once also(even went so far as to use the glitch/bug/feature to use IMAWAL on the boss until i got all the boons of mystera) but i still ended up short. maybe it sure needs some epic luck then

Comment: got it! used gnome though so i had a lot of mana pots and used the mystera annur trick. thanks man